# WPF C#: Increase MainWindow width dynamically on page load

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create an animation by using for loop when I load into page by increasing it's width and position. My problem is that `Application.Current.MainWindow.Width` in the `Page_Loaded` for loop doesn't work. While it works perfectly when leaving the page. My Code:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (double i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left - 2;
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width + 4;
        }
}

private void Home_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.GoBack();
        for (double i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Left = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left + 2;
                Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width - 4;
        }
}
```

When I go to the intended page, my window just moves to the left but the width doesn't increase until the page is completely loaded and it just jumps to the final width rather than animate that. When I leave the page, both my window and width are being changed together.

Is there some limitation when setting the width under Page_Loaded? If so, how can I get over this?

XAML Settings

```
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Loaded="Page_Loaded"
  Title="DatabaseViewer">

<Grid >
    <TextBlock Height="75" Margin="65,20,65,0" Text="Solder Paste Database" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <Button Margin="0,17,30,0" Width="50" Height="50" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" Click="Export_Click"
            Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" ToolTip="Export to Excel">
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Width="40" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Green">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_office_excel}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <DataGrid Name="dbGrid" Width="750" Height="340" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" PreviewKeyDown="dbGrid_KeyDown" GridLinesVisibility="All"
              BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" SelectionChanged="dbGrid_SelectionChanged" >
    </DataGrid>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,70,25,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="115"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Selected Count: " HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="selectedCount" />

    </Grid>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="25,70,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Width="150" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="TB" ToolTip="Column Name = Value [&amp; Column Name = Value]"/>
        <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" FontSize="14" Width="80" Content="Filter" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="filter_click" />
        <Label Grid.Column="2" x:Name="filterLabel" Content="Invalid Search" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>

    <Button Margin="20,27,0,0" Width="30" Height="30" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Home_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" BorderBrush="White"
        Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" >
        <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30"
           Fill="#41b1ff">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_arrow_left}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width + 4; });` I tried this and didn't work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-automatically-size-a-window-to-fit-its-content

Comment: Can you post the XAML of the properties of the window you are trying to animate. It's working on my end so I am curious as to what could be blocking it.

Comment: Using **Dispatcher.Invoke** is rather pointless when you are already on the UI thread

Comment: @Tronald I updated the question with XAML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using explicit code to change dimensions in a loop will most likely result in batching as you have seen. Not to mention you are blocking the UI during all this so I am rather surprised you saw anything change during the loop.

The correct way to essentially *animate* is to use WPF Storyboards.   Here you would define your start and end conditions, what it is you want to animate (width, Left) and how long the animation should run for and tell it to play.   Storyboards then run without you needing to do anything more.   You can define it in code or straight-up XAML.

- [Tell me more...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview)

Comment: Awesome, I used the C# to create and handle the animation and it worked. `DoubleAnimation mydoubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation();
mydoubleanimation.From = 600;
mydoubleanimation.To = 800;
mydoubleanimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Storyboard.SetTarget(mydoubleanimation, Application.Current.MainWindow);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(mydoubleanimation, new PropertyPath(MainWindow.WidthProperty));
Storyboard mystoryboard = new Storyboard();
mystoryboard.Children.Add(mydoubleanimation);
mystoryboard.Begin(this);`

Answer (score 1):

MickyD is right, a Storyboard is the best bet in this situation. Though I can achieve what you want through looping in the code-behind, the result is often buggy as you have seen. In your situation for example you would want to make a `DoubleAnimation` for expansion in your Windows resources.

XAML

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="sb2">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myWindowName" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="500" To="1200" Duration="0:0:3"  AutoReverse="False"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myWindowName" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left" From="500" To="200" Duration="0:0:3"  AutoReverse="False"/>
    </Storyboard>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Then in your Window (or Controls) `Loaded` event

```
 private void myWindowName_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      //Reference System.Windows.Media.Animation;
      Storyboard storyBoardIn = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("sb2");
      storyBoardIn.Begin();
 }
```

You will obviously need to change your storyboard params in XAML to acheive the exact thing you want. This solution is less code and more reliable in WPF. Best of luck!

Comment: This works when done in a window but when I try to reference it in my page by no animation takes place. `MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.increase_width();`

Comment: That’s because you have to call your existing window not create a new one. You can pass the existing one through your pages constructor.